# AWS Boto3 How To Apply Tags to AMI Created From 'import_image'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ami

I have a Lambda function that fires whenever an OVA file is uploaded to an S3 bucket, it should then trigger an AMI to be created based off it.

I am able to use boto.client('ec2').import_image() to create the import_image task which will create the AMI when completed.
The issue I am facing is applying Tags to what will be the created AMI. Specifically a tag with a key of 'name'.

Doing the below I can apply the Tags to the import-image-tasks with the TagSpecification parameter. I can verify that these tags are on the task with 'aws ec2 describe-import-tasks' , but when the task is completed these Tags are not applied to the created AMI in the registry.

I am assuming that I am not applying the Tags correctly. Or I will need to wait for the Task to complete, and then apply the Tags to the created AMI ID. But this process would cause me to have to wait for many minutes for it to complete based on OVA size.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

...

import_vmdk = ec2.import_image(
        Description='test',
        DiskContainers=[
            {
                'Description': '',
                'Format': 'ova',
                'UserBucket': {
                    'S3Bucket': bucket,
                    'S3Key': key
                }
            }
        ],
        LicenseType='BYOL',
        TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType':"snapshot",
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'name',
                    'Value': ami_name
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
    )
```

Comment: Try using `'ResourceType':"image"`, since that is what is being created by the command.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried that previously and it generates the following error:
"An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ImportImage operation: 'image' is not a valid taggable resource type for this operation."

I have looked through this document for the corresponding  AWS CLI command for all options that can be applied to 'ResourceType'  but to be honest I do not have enough experience to know the correct one without trying what seems like the closest term till I run out of option.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/import-image.html

Comment: `import-image-task`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein 'import-image-task' will create tags on the import task, which I can see by describing the import task. But the tags are not applied to the AMI that it generates.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `import-image`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.import_image) says:

> The tags to apply to the import image task during creation.

It does *not* suggest that any Tags are copied from this task to any AMIs created from the command.

So, it **appears to be operating as documented**.

Note that this is slightly different to the [`create_image()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_image) command, which says:

> The tags to apply to the AMI and snapshots on creation.

Comment: so to be clear, there is not a way to directly trigger a conversion of an OVA to an AMI, and have the resulting AMI have Tags applied to it? That is without triggering the task, and then waiting for the task to complete, the pulling the generated AMI id and applying Tags to that ID? I only ask because reading the create_image documentation it assumes that you are creating an AMI from another EBS instance and in my use case I am starting with an OVA file.

Comment: Correct. It is available for `create-image`, but not for `import-image`.